# Typeahead.js on Blur Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js

I'm using the [Twitter Typeahead](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js). There is an issue when I have preloaded data in my text box and on the `blur` event, the text box is clearing. This is a known [issue](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/28) within the type ahead and it says it was fixed. But I can't quite figure out how to implement the fix.

I have my typeahead initialize like this in the `(document).ready` function

```
$('#myTextbox').typeahead({
    name: 'Typeahead',
    valueKey: "Value",
    remote: '/ServiceHandlers/myHandler.ashx?Method=Typeahead&Query=%QUERY',
    template: ['<p>{{Value}}</p>'],
    engine: Hogan
});
```

The issue says to add something like

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead('setQuery', '');
```

But I can't quite see where this would go. Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried putting `$('#myTextbox').typeahead('setQuery', '');` after the code that initializes the typeahead?

Comment: Yes. This just seems to set the query, and therefore the text in the textbox to blank on blur. Causing the same problem as it has now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Figured it out!

Just had to set

```
$('#myTextbox').typeahead('setQuery', $(#myTextbox).val());
```

in the `typeahead.open` function.

Comment: API has changed. It's now $('#myTextbox').typeahead('val', $(#myTextbox).val());

Comment: Hello. I still don't get it to work properly. What Problems I have is that when I see the results and try to navigate threw them (up/down) input is emptied. how to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

Here was my solution:

```js
var typeaheadElement = $('element-selector');
typeaheadElement.bind('typeahead:open', function() {
  typeaheadElement.typeahead('val', typeaheadElement.val());
});
```

Comment: A nice simple solution. Worked great for me.